# Facebook API Login not connecting with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

i have visited all of the below links but can,t solve my problem from it
[Facebook api - login problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049443/facebook-api-login-problem)
[Cannot login through Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139049/cannot-login-through-facebook)
[facebook login, getuser not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951356/facebook-login-getuser-not-working-properly)
[creating facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837049/creating-facebook-application)
[How do I get Facebook Application Login to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534118/how-do-i-get-facebook-application-login-to-work)
[Can't login via facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704495/cant-login-via-facebook-api)
[Facebook OAuth api login problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381903/facebook-oauth-api-login-problems)

the problem is i have created i developer account and create a facebook app and download ths sdk php script. and upload on my server and just test his example file. but its not working and giving me the error:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
and not connecting with the facebook. here is the link to my example file. please anyone suggest the solution.
http://webdesigncc.info/demoz/myfacebook/examples/example.php[image]

where to make changes. in aap info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `www` in the `redirect_uri` supplied to facebook php (`$facebook->getLoginUrl()`). Just replace your `redirect_uri` with `http://www.webdesigncc.info/demoz/myfacebook/examples/example.php` and it will do the trick.

Comment: Are you sure? I checked your link and added www to the link and it worked. Can you paste your `$facebook->getLoginUrl()` here.

Comment: thanks brother i haven,t added www now added and it works thanks alot

Comment: there is another problem how to unset the facebook getUser object because when i click on logout and than come back to the page from another page the user info is still there

Comment: Could you post the above as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `Website with Facebook Login` option to: http://webdesigncc.info

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/558722140837193/summary/

Answer (score 0):

add ur domain 'http://webdesigncc.info' in the App Domains section ..

Answer (score 0):

Just try to leave the fields "`App Domains`" and "`Site URL`" empty. They are for security reasons, AFAIK. In our App, they are empty.